# Using multiple identical flags in curl with Python's sh module

Tags: python, curl

I'm using the sh module in Python to convert my curl commands into Python, but I get an error because I'm using multiple F flags in the curl call in Python.

Here is the original curl code:

```
curl -u admin:admin -F x=y http://localhost:8080/foo
curl -u admin:admin -F :operation=copy -F :dest=/foo/bar http://localhost:8080/foo
```

My code is here:

```
def exploit(url, username, password):
    sh.curl(url, F = "x=y", u = "%s:%s" %(username, password))
    sh.curl(url, F = ":operation=copy", F = ":dest=/foo/bar", u = "%s:%s" %(username, password))

def main():
    #default username and password is admin:admin
    username = "admin"
    password = "admin"
    exploit("http://localhost:8080/foo", username, password)
```

Here's the error message:

```
  File "/Users/Winston/Desktop/sling_exploit.py", line 7
sh.curl(url, F = ":operation=copy", F = ":dest=/foo/bar", u = "%s:%s" %(username, password))
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

Can anyone help me find a solution? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From a glance at the documentation, this doesn't appear to be a usage that `sh` supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using PyCurl for those who are interested

```
def exploit(url, username, password):
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, url)
    data = [
         ('x', 'y')
    ]
    c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, data)
    c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, username + ':' + password)
    c.perform()
    data_2 = [
         (':operation', 'copy'),
         (':dest', '/foo/bar')
    ]
    c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, data_2)
    c.perform()
    c.close()

def main():
    #default username and password is admin:admin
    username = "admin"
    password = "admin"
    exploit("http://localhost:8080/foo", username, password)
```